# How to get data from 2 or more websites at the same time?(Android app)

Tags: java, android, jsoup

I've made an app which gets data from different urls. I used a `for` loop to get data from different urls using jsoup lib. Now this takes a lot of time like 5 sec.
First get data from url1 and then 2 and then 3..
This is what taking the time I think.

So I want to know whether we can get data from different urls at the same time(Multiple threads) or not?

```
public  class Title extends AsyncTask <String, Void, Void> {

    String url,ver;
    Bitmap mIcon11 = null;
    ArrayList<App> appsList = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String ... strings) {
        try {

            for (String string : strings) {
                Document document = Jsoup.connect(string).get();

                Elements a = document.select("div.AppCont");
                Elements b = a.select("article");
                Elements c = b.select("div.ImgDiv");
                Elements d = c.select("img");
                url = d.attr("src");

                InputStream in = new URL(url).openStream();
                mIcon11 = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);

                ver = b.get(0).text();
                String z = string.replace("https://a2zapk.com/History/", "");
                z = z.replace("/", "");

                PackageInfo pi = getApplicationContext().getPackageManager().getPackageInfo((z), PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);
                String versionName = pi.versionName;

                ver = ver + " (Installed Version: " +versionName + ")";
                appsList.add(new App(ver, mIcon11));

            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
         add(appsList);
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You absolutely can, but managing the threading for these tasks can get tricky. I would recommend using [Rxava](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava) to prepare a separate observable for each site you'd like to fetch data from. Then use either [merge](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/Combining-Observables#merge) or [mergeDelayError](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/Combining-Observables#mergedelayerror-example) to merge results into a single Observable that you can subscribe to on the main thread to update your UI.

Check out [RxJavaAndroid](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxAndroid) for help subscribing to these updates on Android's main thread.

You'll want to be familiar with 4 core pieces of RxJava:

1. What you're doing - In your case, this is fetching data from a server
2. What thread pool is running this task - I'd recommend Schedulers.io() which is a pool set aside specifically for IO tasks like fetching data.
3. What thread pool you'll be observing results on - AndroidSchedulers.mainThread() is what you'll want here
4. What to do with the results - Update some UI, etc.

This would look something like the following using RxJava (in Kotlin)

```
// What you're doing
Observable.fromCallable {
    listOfApps = parseAppsList(Jsoup.connect("server1.host.com"))
    return@fromCallable listOfApps
}
        // Where you're doing it
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        // Where you're observing results
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        // What you're doing with those results
        .subscribe({ apps ->
            appsList.addAll(apps)
        }, { exception -> 
            // Show an error message
        })
```

To fetch multiple results simultaneously and add them as each finishes, your code would look something like this:

```
val fromServer1 = Observable.fromCallable {
    listOfApps = parseAppsList(Jsoup.connect("server1.host.com"))
    return@fromCallable listOfApps
}
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())


val fromServer2 = Observable.fromCallable {
    listOfApps = parseAppsList(Jsoup.connect("server2.host.com"))
    return@fromCallable listOfApps
}
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())


Observable.merge(fromServer1, fromServer2)
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .subscribe({ apps ->
            // Note that this callback will be called once per server
            appsList.addAll(apps)
        }, { exception ->
            // Show an error message
        })
```

Comment: Can u elaborate pls ?Cause im very new to this Rxjava

Comment: @RevanthArukala I've added some more context about how RxJava works and a high level of how it could be used in your situation.

Comment: Worked perfectly. I created observables seperately for each site and subscribe to main thread as u said earlier and it worked. Merging is not neccesary as i was working with arraylists. Now time taken to load is 3 sec.(Previously it was 6 sec).Thanks